# Django 'ImportError: cannot import name url'

Tags: django

Hi could anyone help me fix 'ImportError: cannot import name url' problem?
I have followed tutorial here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

I have tried another tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.include
but neither of them worked 
My Django version is 1.11.20

> Performing system checks...
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by                                            Traceback
>   (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 228, in wrapper                            fn(*args, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
>   line 124, in inner_run        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 359, in check
>   include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 346, in _run_checks                    return
>   checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
>   line 81, in run_checks                      new_errors =
>   check(app_configs=app_configs)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
>   line 16, in check_url_config                    return
>   check_resolver(resolver)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
>   line 26, in check_resolver                      return check_method() 
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
>   line 256, in check                                for pattern in
>   self.url_patterns:
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
>   line 35, in **get**                             res =
>   instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
>   line 407, in url_patterns                         patterns =
>   getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
>   line 35, in **get**                             res =
>   instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
>   line 400, in urlconf_module                       return
>   import_module(self.urlconf_name)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in
>   import_module
>   **import**(name)                                                                                                      File "/home/adduser/cantera_correction/mysite/urls.py", line 16, in
>                                                 from
>   django.conf.urls import include, path
>   ImportError: cannot import name path

Comment: Were gonna need a bit more information, such as a full error stack trace, as well as maybe your urls.py

Answer (score 5):

[**path** was introduced in django since Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax). So, if you are using Django 1.11, then you can't use it. You need to define [urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example) like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    # rest of the urls
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view()),

]
```

Answer (score 1):

correct your imports to this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```