# import error in python in django framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import url
from . import views 


urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about/$',views.about),
    url(r'^$',views.homepage),
]
```

this is python code in django framework .
i have successfully installed django but i dont know why this is showing an error .

actually i was just started with django so have a look in the fault .

may be this is because of that it cant reach to urls and contrib directory .
please help 
Thanks in advance

.

```
C:\Users\My Loptop\Desktop\django\djangonautic>
C:\Users\My Loptop\Desktop\django\djangonautic>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\My Loptop\Desktop\django\djangonautic\djangonautic\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name 'url'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 'ImportError: cannot import name url'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545264/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-url)

Answer (score 0):

url imports from [django.conf.urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#module-django.conf.urls)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

Comment: same as previous!!

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: my django version  is 3.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Try use path insted of url, see more in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/), it's very good

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views 


urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/',views.about, name='about'),
    path('',views.homepage, name='home-page'),
]
```